# How to hide certain icons from unity app lens

Tags: icons, settings, system

Ok, so unity is great and all, but something that annoys me that the various systems settings apps show up in the app lens, I don't need them there because there's the system settings menu.  Is there anyway to remove particular icons from the apps lens while still keeping them installed?

Answer (score 0):

No, there isn't really a way to keep them in the System Settings, but hidden in the dash. But why bother with the System Settings app at all, when you can open the one you want, right from the dash? :)

Comment: Personal preference?